How to use Stream.collect with specific class as suplider
I am a student.
You might think I'm overloading the code with this, unnecessarily, but the goal is just to improve the understanding of the collect method. So all these components that I mention are part of the topic, and the goal is to solve the error, not another way to get the same result, so don't suggest me other ways than why this doesn't work! Thanks in advance. So here is the code:
package konekcija;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
public class app {

  private JFrame okvir;
  private JList lst;
  private JLabel[] conn = new JLabel[20];
  private JTextField txt;
  private JPanel[] pnl = new JPanel[20];
  private JButton query[] = new JButton[20];
  private JToolBar box;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      var app = new app();
      app.okvir.setVisible(true);

    });
  }

  public app() {
    this.initialize();

  }
record Counting(HashMap<JPanel,Integer> hm){
public Counting() {
  this(new HashMap<JPanel,Integer> ());// odnos glavnog yapisa i adicionih svojstava u nekanonskom konstrunktu
  
}
  public void accumulator(JPanel p) {
    this.hm.put(p, 1);
    
  }
    
   // samo da ukazem na to da se iako su polja kao u nekoj POJO oznakom final, ne znaci da je sadrzaj ref konacan
    public void combiner(Counting cn) {
      var key = cn.hm().keySet().stream().findFirst().get();
   this.hm.put(key, (int)this.hm.getOrDefault(key,0)+1);
  
    }
    }
private void initialize() {


   okvir = new JFrame();
  okvir.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
  okvir.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  okvir.setBounds(000, 0000, 1880, 1880);
  okvir.setResizable(false);
okvir.setTitle("PREDUZEĆE");



  Stream.of( (Stream.of(this.pnl).limit(3)
      .collect(new Counting(),(c,p)->((Counting) c).accumulator(p), 
             (c1,c2)->((Counting) c2).combiner((Counting) 
              c1))).hm().entrySet()).peek((entry)->{
                   var idx=entry.getValue();
                   var pnl=entry.getKey();
                   switch(idx) {
                         case 1:
                            pnl.setBounds(0,0,idx*100,100);
                            break;
                         case 2:
                            pnl.setBounds(0,0,idx*100,100);
                            break;
                         case 3:
                            pnl.setBounds(0,0,idx*100,100);
                            break;
                         default:
                            break;
                        }
                   }).close();
} }



The problem is in the part related to collect, which doesn't understand that the record "Counting" is my container-suplider. In the book, I saw that the same techniques are used, or some predefined classes like HashMap or List are specified, but it's the same. Where am I wrong.Not to confuse, after collect there was an error, and regardless of it, I wrote the rest of the stream, by heart, just so that I had a complete whole, so now I'm looking to fix the part. And here I have two Streams, one will take the field hm from the passed Counting-s, using the method hm() and extract the entrySet, and then generate a new stream (external) from it.

.collect() requires as first parameter either a Supplier or a Collector. Your Counting is neither. In particular seems to fail to implement the Collector interface

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
The method collect(Supplier, BiConsumer<R,? super JPanel>, BiConsumer<R,R>) in the type Stream is not applicable for the arguments (app.Counting, BiConsumer<R,? super JPanel>, BiConsumer<R,R>)
from JVM

@VLAZ how to fix the error, so that this works, that is, as in the Java CoockBook by Ian.F.Darwin there is an example with HashMap,
.collect(new HashMap<.,.>(),(m,k)->m.put(v,(int)getOrDefault(k,0)+1),(m1,m2)->m1.putAll( m2)),
but this doesn't work for me either, ahhhhhh my bad life , i think i'm stupid :(

Make Counting properly implement Collector. Start with record Counting implements Counting then continue to fix the implementation in order to conform.

Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

@Brasil Bourque, i do.

new Counting() creates one instance, but a supplier can create an arbiratray number of instances. Just use Counting::new as supplier. It’s equivalent to () -> new Counting(). Then, remove all those unnecessary type casts, to make the code readable. Don’t use Stream.of(…) for arrays, that’s easy to confuse with the single argument call (to create a stream with the array object as its sole element). Use Arrays.stream(pnl) instead. This even allows you to use Arrays.stream(pnl, 0, 3) to stream over the first three element, avoiding the costs of limit(3).

Finally, this Stream.of(collection).peek(…).close(…) is a triple error. None of the three methods will do what you seem to think it will do. To perform an action for each entry of a map, just use map.forEach((key, value) -> …). But the way, if the book really use new HashMap<…>() rather than HashMap::new, then it’s a really bad book. An author who thinks they can explain the Stream API to others should understand the difference between an object and a supplier of objects.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
